# How to apply quadratic drag force to a body in cannon.js?

Tags: game-physics, cannon.js

I want to apply a drag force to a [cannon.js' body](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Body.html), I've tried in a way but it's breaking the physics, wanted to know if there is a more correct way or if someone has already done something similar.

There is a property of the body called `linearDamping`, it's a drag force linearly proportional to the velocity, however I am trying to implement the fluid drag force formula, to achieve more realism.

The simplified formula is this one, as you can see it's quadratically proportional to the velocity:

`Fd = - Constant * getMagnitude(velocity)**2 * normalize(velocity)`

I have implemented in the cannon.js this way, using the [Vec3](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Vec3.html) methods. Note that I call `applyDrag` every update:

```
applyDrag(coefficient) {
  const speed = body.velocity.length()

  const dragMagnitude = coefficient * Math.pow(speed, 2)

  const drag = body.velocity.clone()
  drag.scale(-1, drag)

  drag.normalize()

  drag.scale(dragMagnitude, drag)

  body.applyLocalForce(drag, new CANNON.Vec3())
}
```

However this sorta breaks, and the objects go crazy.
Is there a better way to apply some sort of `quadraticDamping`?

[This is the part where `linearDamping` is applied](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/blob/569730f94a1d9da47967a24fad0323ef7d5b4119/src/world/World.js#L856-L870), I am having difficulties understanding fully that code and trying to implement a quadratic damping the right way.

Answer (score 3):

Solved!  I didn't get that also the direction of the force vector is local, here is the solution:

```
applyDrag(coefficient) {
  const speed = body.velocity.length()

  const dragMagnitude = coefficient * Math.pow(speed, 2)

  const drag = body.velocity.clone()
  drag.scale(-1, drag)

  drag.normalize()

  drag.scale(dragMagnitude, drag)

  const centerInWorldCoords = body.pointToWorldFrame(new CANNON.Vec3())
  body.applyForce(force, centerInWorldCoords)
}
```